# error: Module "strawberry.scalars" has no attribute "JSON"

Tags: python, strawberry-graphql

According to the strawberry documentation (https://strawberry.rocks/docs/types/scalars) the JSON scalar type is available in strawberry.scalars.
But it throws an error when it is imported:

`error: Module "strawberry.scalars" has no attribute "JSON"`

Do you have any idea why it can not be found?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippit that shows both how you are importing strawberry as well as how you are calling the line with .JSON?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.